# negatives and positives in lists

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that allows me to add only the positive numbers in a list and only the negative numbers in a list. I don't know where to start with my coding though. Any help would be great thanks!

example:

```
negpos([-5,5,6,-8,9])
```

should return:

```
[-13, 20]
```

Comment: This smells of a homework problem... please tag with `homework` if this is a homework problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this on for size:

```
def negpos (lst):
    (neg, pos) = (0, 0)
    for elem in lst:
        if elem < 0:
            neg = neg + elem
        else:
            pos = pos + elem
    return [neg, pos]

print negpos ([-5,5,6,-8,9])
```

It simply maintains two accumulators and adds to the relevant one. The output is:

```
[-13, 20]
```

as desired.

Comment: Don't use the builtin `list` as a variable name please!

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me understand because it was so simple! :)

Comment: @97834657647563 (you couldn't have picked an easier name, could you?): since you've now tagged it as homework, make sure you don't use my solution verbatim. Good educators will be checking sites like these and plagiarism is almost certainly a failing offence. My advice is to read and understand then go away and implement it yourself a day later.

Comment: @paxdiablo Oh no, definitely won't. Some kid in my class got caught using stackoverflow. I change the problems before I post them on here then further research soultions using docs.python.org then write my own coding.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter) and [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum). The first argument to `filter` is a function that returns True if the value should be included, and False if it should not. Pass a function to it the first time that only selects integers less than 0, and the second time pass one that only selects integers greater than 0, then pass the resulting list to `sum`. If you need help past that, just add a comment and I'll help, but I think you'll learn more than if I just give you straight source code.

Comment: A filtered generator expression will usually be clearer these days than using the `filter` function.

Answer (score 1):

Generator expressions can make life easy and highly efficient:

```
def negpos( inlist ):
    p = sum(x for x in inlist if x > 0)
    n = sum(x for x in inlist if x < 0)
    return (n,p)
```

It might also be more appropriate to return a fixed tuple than a list, which I have done.

Comment: Is this actually more efficient [paxdiablo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061630/negatives-and-positives-in-lists/5061648#5061648)?  It seems that a single pass `for` loop may still be the best approach here.

Comment: Don't know about efficiency, @D. Only know that I tend to steer clear of what many call the Pythonic way even though it's shorter and, quite possibly, better for that. But that's because I use it as a language for teaching kids. I mourn what Guido has done to my beautiful language :-)

Comment: @D. Shawley: "Best" is a relative term. Pax' solution (+1) is single pass and more efficient but Seth's solution is half the code and more expressive. I think that 80% of the time I would opt for a more readable and maintainable code over efficient code. It all depends on how much and how often. If the array is thousands of integers, go with Pax, if it's a few dozen, keep it short.

Comment: It's probably slightly less efficient (`timeit` would tell us for sure), but the structure is better, and easier to adapt to different requirements.

Comment: @paxdiablo: I am a Python n00b. Would you mind expanding or providing a link on `I mourn what Guido has done to my beautiful language` please?

Comment: @D.: I originally misread the post, thinking it asked for all the positive elements, in which case a list comprehension would be readable, efficient, and easy. Since my example has to take two passes, it's clearly not as efficient. But in general, generators can make life efficient. :)

Comment: @pax: jokes about it being "your language" aside, generator expressions and list comprehensions, along with many of the other Pythonic constructs such as `enumerate`, `range`, etc. have the advantage of consolidating all the intent of a code block in a single place, rather than scattering initialization, incrementing, and value checking among a larger chunk of code.

Comment: @Paul, I'm just having a dig. Most of Python is good for teaching the base concepts of sequence, iteration and selection but things that make programmers lives easier (like generators) tend toward hiding those concepts (at least the explicit nature of them). @Seth's answer is not bad, even in that context, since the iteration and selection are still there. It's just easier (for me) to teach more verbose stuff. Something like a language that has negpos implemented as `neg = apply(sum,iterate,select(<0),x)`, for example, would teach nothing.

Comment: @Paul: over time, Python has acquired a variety of features to make certain operations more efficient and/or easier to write correctly. This has inevitably made the language harder to learn, since there are now multiple ways to do things, and it isn't always clear when the new "better" ways apply. This question is a good example, since the generator expression approach requires two passes, while the simple `for` loop only needs a single pass, but is significantly less flexible.

Comment: @pax: Note that Guido has strongly moved against those more opaque expressions (map, reduce, apply, etc.) in favor of the much more obvious generator expressions. Python has been trying to move toward increasing clarity; do you think that `i = 0; while i < 5: print i; i = i + 1` is clearer than `for i in range(5): print i` ?

Comment: No, but I've used range. I haven't used all those other things :-)

Answer (score 0):

without any fancy stuff

```
>>> neg=0
>>> pos=0
>>> for i in [-5,5,6,-8,9]:
...   if i<0: neg+=i
...   if i>0: pos+=i
...
>>> print neg,pos
-13 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sum` with a filtered generator expression is the easiest way to add up a subset of a sequence:

```
positive_tally = sum(x for x in seq if x > 0)
negative_tally = sum(x for x in seq if x < 0)
```

Combining those into a single `negpos` function would be easy enough, but probably unnecessary unless you're doing this in several different places.

Out of curiousity, I decided to do the actual timing comparison between the generator expression approach and the simple `for` loop:

```
code1 = """
data = [-5,5,6,-8,9]
def negpos(seq):
  neg, pos = 0, 0
  for x in seq:
    if x >= 0:
      pos += x
    else:
      neg += x
  return neg, pos
"""
code2 = """
data = [-5,5,6,-8,9]
def negpos(seq):
  neg = sum(x for x in seq if x < 0)
  pos = sum(x for x in seq if x > 0)
  return neg, pos
"""
command = "negpos(data)"
timer1 = timeit.Timer(command, code1)
timer2 = timeit.Timer(command, code2)
timer1.repeat()
timer2.repeat()
```

On my system, the dedicated `for` loop comes out as being roughly twice as fast (that's not particularly surprising, since the loop is executed twice with the generator based approach, but it is still interesting to confirm it).

Answer (score 0):

```
import functools
import operator

ltzero = functools.partial(operator.ge, 0)  # 0>=num -> num<0
gtzero = functools.partial(operator.le, 0)  # 0<=num -> num>0

def negpos(lst):
    return [sum(filter(ltzero, lst)), sum(filter(gtzero, lst))]

negpos([-5,5,6,-8,9])  # ->  [-13, 20]
```